# JQuery Undefined Error AutoComplete

Tags: jquery

I have a JQuery Error with the following script. When I run the script an alert pops up and says 'Undefined'. I did search and found that the common causes are script order and the CDN is down. The CDN is not don because I referenced the script on another page and it works fine. I did an alert as a test and my Javascript is working fine. Third I put the script and the bottom of the page and I still got the same error. Fourth, I do not have a conflict with another script on the page because it is the only one.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript">  
        $(function () {
            $("#txtCity").autocomplete({
                source: function (request, response) {
                    var param = { cityname: $('#txtCity').val() };
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "testAutoComplete.aspx/GetCities",
                        data: JSON.stringify(param),
                        dataType: "json",
                        type: "POST",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataFilter: function (data) { return data; },
                        success: function (data) {
                            response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                                return {
                                    value: item
                                }
                            }))
                        },
                        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            alert(errorThrown);
                        }
                    });
                },
                minLength: 2 
            });
        });         
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <asp:Label ID="label1" Text="Enter City: " runat="server" />
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtCity" runat="server" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>

[WebMethod]
public static List<string> GetCities(string cityname)
{
    List<string> City = new List<string>();
    SqlConnection conn;
    SqlCommand comm;
    SqlDataReader reader;
    string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SlotConn"].ConnectionString;
    conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    comm = new SqlCommand("SELECT Cityname FROM City WHERE Cityname LIKE @Cityname", conn);
    comm.Parameters.Add("@Cityname", System.Data.SqlDbType.varchar);
    comm.Parameters["@Cityname"].Value = cityname;
    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        reader = comm.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            City.Add(reader.GetString(0));
        }
    }

    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
    }
    return City;
}
```

Comment: put a console.log inside the success handler and verify you get the correct data as expected.

Comment: I do not even get that far. When I start typing that is when the error is alerted.